# Go from sink to graph nodes in a network flow graph

Tags: algorithm

I know generally you go from source to sink in a network flow graph, but I know there are specific algorithms to go from the sink to a desired node in a network flow graph (not including the source). Could anybody suggest an algorithm that could do this? It's been a while since I've taken an algorithms class and I'm a little rusty on how to go about this one.

Comment: Please add details. What do you want to accomplish? Do you want to find maxflow from the sink to specific vertex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find a flow from the sink to a vertex A, just set `new_source := sink` and `new_sink = A` and run the algorithm of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

how about add a new edge from that desired node to the sink with infinite capacity.